# Problema con variables en c# para un script de unity

Tags: c#, script, unity3d, unity

mi problema es el siguiente estoy haciendo un script en unity para detectar colisiones pero al ejecutarlo me salta el siguiente error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

y el código es el siguiente:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColisionEjemplo : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject musica;


    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag = "Player"){
            musica.SetActive(true);
        }

     }

   }
```

y creo que el error es referido a la forma de expresar la variable GameObject en la línea 12, me gustaria a poder ser que alguien me dijese o me explicase como poder solucionarlo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: necesitas poner doble igual para comparar  un valor con otro: ´other.gameObject.tag == "Player"´

Comment: Primero te recomiendo que trabajes con constantes los tags, para evitar errores en la escritura de los mismos. Otra recomendación que te hago es que utilices los layers en ves de tags ya que en procesamiento les cuentas menos validar. Verifica si esta bien escrito el tag y sí esta haciendo la validación en la escena correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo visualizo cuando defines la validacion en el `if`

```
if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
```

para comparar debes usar `==`